# How add scroll in the jtable body using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jtable, jquery-jtable

I have a Jtable as shown bellow:
[image]

I want to add scrollbar to my JTable body and resize the table height to show only 4 rows in the body using jQuery and CSS. 
Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved by just putting a scrollbar using the inline CSS with my div tag.

```
<div style="height:250px; width:100%; overflow-y:scroll" id="ProductDetails"></div></td>
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Your question specifically asked to scroll the table body. Your solution does not answer you own question, as it will scroll the table in the div.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial issue. [Here is a whole tutorial on the subject of scrolling a JTable](http://www.swaleinternet.co.uk/tutorials/jTable-demo-table-scroll.php)